# How to check whether inserting fails?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, try-catch

Here is my script:

```
try {

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare(" INSERT INTO mytable ( col ) VALUES ( ? ) ");
    $inserting = $stmt->execute( array('anything') );

    if ( $inserting ) {
        echo 'successful';

    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }

} catch(PDOException $e){ 

    echo 'failed';
}
```

**What's my question:** All I want to know, `else` and `catch` are the same in my script? In other word when `else` executes?

I think `else` never executes, because if `$inserting == false` then it jumps to the `catch` block, then `else` never run. Am I right? Writing that `else` is useless?

Comment: Why do you want to know it? What would you do if not?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I want to know should I write that `else` or remove it of my codes.

Comment: you should remove both else and catch

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Most of time you don't want to know if a particular insert failed. But rather if your site is working all right or not. So in general your code should be just

```
$stmt = $db_con->prepare(" INSERT INTO mytable ( col ) VALUES ( ? ) ");
$stmt->execute( array('anything') );
echo 'successful';
```

with both else and catch being useless.

However, sometimes you may want catch a **certain error**. In this case use catch. Here is a [code from my article](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors):

```
try {
    $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)")->execute($data);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 1062) {
        // Take some action if there is a key constraint violation, i.e. duplicate name
    } else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

here you may catch a certain error and handle it.

Comment: Well I need to write my inserting code into a `try-catch` block ..! My question is about that `if-else` statement.

Comment: Your second code is good. FYI `(int) $e->getCode() === 23000` means duplicate, not `1062`. And also I need to know inserting is successful or not

Comment: Your insert is always successful unless there is an error. You don't need any special code to handle successful inserts.

Comment: Just for my information, that `NULL` is for `id` column?

Comment: Yes. But you still didn't answer my question, why do you want to know were insert was successful or not.

Comment: Actually I need to redirect current page to somewhere ... if inserting successful, then it should be redirect to *login* page, else it should be redirect to *register* page.

Comment: That's what you are doing wrong. You should never redirect on error.

Comment: Why? I always do that and all fine ..! I set a session based on the error and then redirect it to somewhere plus showing that error (`echo $_session['err']`)

Comment: There is a thing called HTTP. A standard that defines the behavior of a web-site, you know.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i'll suggest you use

```
if($inserting->rowCount()==1){
    echo 'successful';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

to find out if it actually inserted.

The **else** statment is not useless. 
If your query doesnt insert due to a pdo error, then the **catch statement** will catch the error. But if it doesnt insert without any pdo errors and number of rows is 0 then the else statement will run

Answer (score 0):

## Try a different output

If you're trying to work out which block is executing, the simplest idea would be to change what's echoed based on which block you hit.

```
try {
    if (...) {
        ...
    } else {
        echo "Failed: Some Message";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Failed: Some Other Message";
}
```

Alternatively, you can put a logger function, or some other debug function.

Comment: this is a comment, not answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense No, he asked how to tell when `else` executes. My answer tells him how to tell when `else` executes.