# What's wrong with redirecting on error?

Tags: php, redirect, pdo

I have a script like this:

```
try {
    $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)")->execute($data);
    $_SESSION['state'] = 'done';
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 1062) {
        $_SESSION['state'] = 'duplicate';
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        exit;

    } else {
        $_SESSION['state'] = 'fail';
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        exit;
    }
}
```

But I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343185/how-to-check-whether-inserting-fails#comment62204593_37343674) I shouldn't redirect on error. Why? What's wrong with it? I've tested my script several times and it works as well and all fine. Has it a problem with HTTP request? Or what's the problem?

Comment: As the original commenter stated, the HTTP standard dictates that server errors should be indicated by a 5xx error, not a redirect. If you don't care about scripts (including search engines) understanding your site, then doing a redirect instead of throwing an error probably doesn't matter.

Comment: In your case it's also a sign of a wrong code structure. 

Writing a distinct PHP script for the every possible action is a fatal overlkill. Soon you will be drowning in thousands of files.

Comment: @YourCommonSense In reality there isn't multiple files .. It always redirects to previous page. Is that fine now?

Comment: @Chris What do you mean `5xx` ?

Comment: Nope. For a duplicate you may keep with redirect, but for other errors it should be just a termination.

Comment: In your case, you're relying on HTTP_REFERER which can be any random page (or none at all). Sooner or later you'll generate an ampty `Location:` header.

Comment: @stack Chris means that you should set a HTTP status. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php . Though I wonder if setting http status to 500 and doing header Location redirect are mutually exclusive. Why not both ?

Comment: @nl-x Because a response can only have one status code.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález A header redirect is not a status code.

Comment: One more thought: when the user tries to insert a duplicate record it can hardly be considered a server error when the server is clearly designed to support that scenario.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have a condition before running that script: `if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ) { /* script executes */ } `

Comment: @nl-x Er... Yes, [it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx).

Comment: @nl-x I got what Chris means. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Ok, what about setting something like this `header("HTTP/1.0 400 Not Found");` before redirecting?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález No, it is not. Try it. `<?php header('Location: /redirected.php');
header('HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error');` This will give you a status 500 WITH a redirect header response. Off course, browsers might not support it. But that was the bit I am unsure about.

Comment: @nl-x Just tried. [Doesn't work](https://i.imgur.com/UFE0z4G.png). And don't blame Firefox, it's doing the right thing, just like [Internet Explorer](https://i.imgur.com/vLle4LM.png) and [Chrome](https://i.imgur.com/Y1vYgmo.png).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yeah, I can understand that the browsers won't deal with it. IIS seems to catch this and give you in the body: `<h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="newurl">here</a>`, but this does not mean you get redirected automatically. Though as you already show in your screenshot, you do get 500 with location header FWIW. But lets just agree on that it won't work to redirect with error 500.